# Grid Column Not Centering Image

Tags: css, semantic-ui-react

I am having trouble getting the Image inside of a semantic-ui-react Grid Column to be centered. The Message I have below the Image is being centered correctly by using

```
textAlign='center'
```

on the Column, but if I try use for example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Row>
        <Grid.Column centered textAlign='center'>
            <Image src={imgsrc} />
            <Message size='small'>Image Title</Message>
        </Grid.Column>
    </Grid.Row>
</Grid>
```

The Image keeps to the left. I can CSS/Flex to position the Image where I want it in the Column, and it may be the correct way to do it, but Should I not be able to simply position the Image in the center of the Grid Column without CSS?

Comment: Will you consider center image in ui image instead of grid view? or grid view is must needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a `div` inside `<Grid.Column>` with class `ui segment`. Then set `class="ui centered medium image"` in Image tag. You can avoid another div just set a class `ui segment` in `<Grid.Column>`. See more [Image](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/image.html) property in Sementic-ui.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Row>
        <Grid.Column>
            <div class="ui segment">
              <img class="ui centered medium image" src={imgsrc}>
            </div>
        </Grid.Column>
    </Grid.Row>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the react.semantic-ui [Image](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/image/) component with "centered" prop like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Row>
        <Grid.Column>
          <Image centered src="" />
        </Grid.Column>
    </Grid.Row>
</Grid>
```